# Continue computation in do while even if no columns exist

Tags: c

What I am trying to do (not very successful) is if my code detects a signal `(if(matrix[i][j] ==1))` coming (1 or 0) for the next few steps I want my code to write in a new matrix: `newmatrix[i][j]=10` and if not to continue with `0`. Here is my code so far:

```
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        j = 0;
        do {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
                int m = j;
                while (j < m + 3) {
                    newmatrix[i][j] = 10;
                    printf("newmatrix[%i][%i] and %f\n", i, j, newmatrix[i][j]);
                    j++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                newmatrix[i][j] = 0;
                printf("newmatrix[%i][%i] and 0 is %f\n", i, j, newmatrix[i][j]);
                j++;
                continue;   
            }
            j++;
        } while (j < MAXTIME);
    }
}
```

The problem is that if there is a signal near the end instead of stopping when to column count reaches the max number the code inserts new columns even though they are only 10:

Where is my mistake can someone point me to the right direction? Is there maybe a way to do this cleaner with `goto` statement?

Comment: share your full code .....!!!!

Comment: Please spend some effort on trying to improve your code formatting if you want to get answers. This time I did it for you, but really this should be the poster's job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach with a temporary variable:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    int spike = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < MAXTIME; j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
           spike = 3;
        }
        if (spike) {
           newmatrix[i][j] = 10;
           spike--;
        } else {
           newmatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
        printf("newmatrix[%i][%i] is %f\n", i, j, newmatrix[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I am assuming that `matrix[i][j]` is either `0` or `1`. If other values are possible and `newmatrix[i][j]` should stay unmodified for these cells, the code should be modified.
- It is advisable to only modify a loop index in the `for` update clause. `do` / `while` loops are notoriously error prone, especially with nested loops that also modify the loop index as is the case in your code.